# Get Cookie issue after login to website using C# HttpWebRequest (Cookie is generated by javascript)

Tags: c#, javascript, httpwebrequest, http-headers

I am doing a project to login a website by C#. 
This website's cookie is created by Javascript, I. can't get it. Do you have any ideas? 
Only after logined I can read resources I need from that website

-----Below is the HTML Content return by HTTPWebRequest-----

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <base href="http://passport.tianya.cn:80/" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <title>Loading......</title>
    <script>
      document.cookie='user=w=testAcount01&id=61847120&f=1;expires='+(new Date(new Date().getTime()+2592000*1000)).toGMTString()+';path=/;domain=tianya.cn';
      document.cookie='temp=k=715580387&s=&t=1324904085&b=270dc20704fefc75b56510d5b2c225c8&ct='+parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000)+'&et=-1;path=/;domain=tianya.cn';
      document.cookie='sso=r=1789338886&sid=&wsid=E329680C729EA57FE7B913A7CB0EB42E;path=/;domain=tianya.cn';
      document.cookie='right=web4=n&portal=n;expires='+(new Date(new Date().getTime()+2592000*1000)).toGMTString()+';path=/;domain=tianya.cn';
      document.cookie='temp4=rm=;expires='+(new Date(new Date().getTime()+2592000*1000)).toGMTString()+';path=/;domain=tianya.cn';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://passport.tianyaclub.com/domain.jsp?cookieTime=1324904085&portalValue=&rightCookie=false&rmCookieCode=&isActivatedUser=&idWriter=61847120&writer=testAcount01&intKey=715580387&chvSysGradeList=&sysGrade=&domain=tianyaclub.com&flag=b868a24deca81f10c73df39b92004b1c&rmCode=false&rmFlag=&wsid=E329680C729EA57FE7B913A7CB0EB42E&r=1789338886"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://passport.hainan.net/domain.jsp?cookieTime=1324904085&portalValue=&rightCookie=false&rmCookieCode=&isActivatedUser=&idWriter=61847120&writer=testAcount01&intKey=715580387&chvSysGradeList=&sysGrade=&domain=hainan.net&flag=b868a24deca81f10c73df39b92004b1c&rmCode=false&rmFlag=&wsid=E329680C729EA57FE7B913A7CB0EB42E&r=1789338886"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://passport.hiholiday.com/domain.jsp?cookieTime=1324904085&portalValue=&rightCookie=false&rmCookieCode=&isActivatedUser=&idWriter=61847120&writer=testAcount01&intKey=715580387&chvSysGradeList=&sysGrade=&domain=hiholiday.com&flag=b868a24deca81f10c73df39b92004b1c&rmCode=false&rmFlag=&wsid=E329680C729EA57FE7B913A7CB0EB42E&r=1789338886"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      location.href="http://my.tianya.cn";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

C# Code:

```
 CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
 string url = "http://passport.tianya.cn/login?vwriter=testAcount01&vpassword=123456abc";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.CookieContainer = container;

        request.BeginGetResponse(call =>
            {
                var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)call.AsyncState;
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.EndGetResponse(call);

                using (var stream = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var content = stream.ReadToEnd();
                }

            }, request);
```

Actually, I need CookieContainer with right cookie and take this as next request container, but this CookieContainer Cookie Count is 0.

PS:

1. The c# above is using GET method to access, I have used POST method with some headers to access, the result is the same.
2. The code should be fine, I have changed another website URL to login, I can get the right Cookie. So I guess its Javascript issue, How can I get it with C#?
3. Please feel free to login/test with the username & password, this account is only for test.

Any idea is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this websites sets its cookies through javascript, I would suggest that you'd try to parse the javascript in C# and try to reconstruct the cookie from that.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I have did it, convert document.cookie='..js cookie string.' to cookie string, and use it as next HTTP request cookie, but it can NOT work, showing not logined. Actually, I need use CookieContainer object, not cookie string...

Comment: How did you pass the cookies to the next request? Have you assigned these cookies to the `CookieContainer`?

Comment: First,convert js string to C# string cookieHeader.  Then          var newRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("newPostLink");
newRequest.CookieContainer = container;
newRequest.CookieContainer.SetCookies(newRequest.RequestUri, cookieHeader);                                                         PS: I think convered JS NewDate() maybe not the same with Server time, how do you think about? Thanks